# How to arrange words in a single row using sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

My file contents:

```
Google
Facebook
yahoo
cisco
juniper
oracle
firetide
attack
```

I wanted to convert the above words(column) into a row as shown below:

```
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

NOTE : There should be a single space between each word.

Please suggest me a way to achieve this using sed or awk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk

```
$ awk 'ORS=FS' inputFile
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

**OR**

Another variation would be

```
$ awk 1 ORS=' ' input
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

Comment: @Kumar You are wlecome :)

Comment: @Jotne But it wont change the record separators, it still remains as `\n`

Comment: A small variation `awk 1 ORS=' ' inputfile`

Comment: @Jotne That is shorter :D Would you mind me adding to my answer?

Answer (score 5):

#### Using shell

If shell solutions are allowable, then try:

```
$ echo $(cat inputfile) 
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

The above should work with any POSIX shell.  With `bash`:

```
$ echo $(<inputfile) 
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

#### Using `sed`

If we really must use `awk` or `sed`, then here is a `sed` solution:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/\n/ /g' inputfile
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

The above reads the whole file in (`:a;N;$!ba`) and then replaces all newlines with spaces (`s/\n/ /g`).

If the input file might contain extra spaces at the beginning for end of a line, we can remove them:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*/ /g' inputfile
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
xargs <file
Google Facebook yahoo cisco juniper oracle firetide attack
```

This also give a newline at the end unlike the `awk` posted.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tr` :

```
tr '\n' ' ' < File
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${x;s/ *\n */ /gp;}' YourFile
```

- replace starting / ending space and new line by a simple space (so any starting space will be removed ).